# Rotating list based on matching elements of a different list

Tags: python

Let's say I have two lists:
List1

```
[26, 45, 15]
```

List2

```
[13, 15, 20]
```

Assuming there is always exactly one element that is the same between the two lists, how would I reorder list2 into:

```
[20, 13, 15]
```

Where 15 becomes the third element of list2 because 15 is the third element of list1 (While the order of 13, 15, and then 20 is kept)? I have tried something like this:

```
# Reorder list2 to correspond with list1
key = 0
newOrder = []
for i in range(3):
   for j in range(3):
            if list2[i] == list1[j]:  # if elements 
                key = i - j
for k in range(3):
   index = k + key
   if index == 3:
            index = 0
   if index == -1:
            index = 2
   newOrder.append(list2[index])
```

but it doesn't have a 100% success rate.

Comment: "(While the sequence of numbers is kept)" Shouldn't it be `[13, 20, 15]` then? Or do you mean you want to "rotate" the list until the matching element is in the right place?

Comment: The sequence is not kept though

Comment: @tobias_k I should have made it more clear. The order stays the same (it will always be in the order of 13, 15, then 20)

Comment: I have a problem understanding this.: `While the order of 13, 15, and then 20 is kept`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to rotate `list2` so that the "shared" element is in the same position as in `list1`.

First, to get the matching indices you do not have to compare all elements. Instead, you can use a dict to store which element is at which position, and then get the matching position in a single pass over `list2` (if the lists always have just 3 elements this does not matter, but for longer lists it reduces the complexity from O(n²) to O(n))

```
list1 = [26, 45, 15]
list2 = [13, 15, 20]
pos2 = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(list2)}
p1, p2 = next((i, pos2[x]) for i, x in enumerate(list1) if x in pos2)
```

Then, you can use a list comprehension to get the "rotated" elements from `list2` using modulo `%` to "wrap around" when the index is larger than the length of the list.

```
n = len(list2)
res = [list2[(i+p2-p1) % n] for i in range(n)]
print(res) # [20, 13, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gets the value and the index of the number in list1 that also exists in list2.

```
list1 = [26, 45, 15]
list2 = [13, 15, 20]

index, number = next((idx,number) for idx, number in enumerate(list1) if number in list2)
```

Then it removes the number from list2 and inserts it again at the wanted index:

```
list2.remove(number)
list2.insert(index,number)

print(list2)
```

Output will be

```
[13, 20, 15]
```

Comment: I tought he wanted the order to stay the same